# Using jquery with spring framework

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I don't have much experience using jquery but I want a rich UI from my application, which is built on spring framework. I am the only developer working on this project and want to know if there is any possibility of using Jquery like GWT ( write once, run every where). Please letme know if there are any issues in using Jquery and Spring or any best practice. Tried ZK, Vaadin, but both ruled out.

Appreciate any help , Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix jQuery code in ZK and GWT code in Vaadin. Both, ZK and Vaadin are very productive and make higly usable UIs. You should try to use one of those.
Finally, ZK has a good integration with Spring.